# python assign multiple values to multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays

My question is:

Lets say I have `N` arrays: arr0, arr1, arr2,... arrN (edit: actually `N+1` arrays, but it doesn't matter) .

I want to insert to the first member of all the arrays values, in the same line, like this:

```
[arr0[0], arr1[0], arr2[0]... arrN[0]]=[0,1,2,3....N]
```

I would expect that after this line `arr0[0]` will be 0, `arr1[0]` will be 1 etc.

but, for some reason, what happends is `arr0[0]=arr1[0]=arr2[0]=...=arrN[0]=N`

Any idea why, and what can I do to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you posted does work as expected (for lists, NumPy arrays and `array.array`s). Can you post more code so the problem is reproducible?

Comment: I initiated all the arrays with 'None' 's - maybe that could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description of the symptom, I'm going to guess you defined the lists like this:

```
arr0, arr1 = [[None]]*2
```

In that case, both `arr0` and `arr1` refer to the *exact same list*, because `[xyz]*2` produces the list `[xyz, xyz]` where `xyz` is the exact same object listed twice.

So when Python encounters `[arr0[0], arr1[0]] = [10, 20]` it first assigns

```
arr0[0] = 10
```

and then

```
arr1[0] = 20
```

but since `arr0` and `arr1` both refer to the same list, the first element in both lists 
is assigned-to twice:

```
In [46]: arr0, arr1 = [[None]]*2
```

Note that assignment to `arr0` affects `arr1`:

```
In [47]: arr0[0] = 10

In [48]: arr1
Out[48]: [10]
```

Note that assignment to `arr1` affects `arr0`:

```
In [49]: arr1[0] = 20

In [50]: arr0
Out[50]: [20]
```

Since the [assignments are evaluated from left to right](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order), the right-most assignment is last and so it is that assignment which ultimately affects both lists `arr0`, `arr1`.

---

**To fix the problem**: Use

```
arr0, arr1 = [None], [None]
```

or

```
arr0, arr1 = [[None] for i in range(2)]
```

since in both cases, `arr0` and `arr1` get assigned to *different lists*.

Comment: hell you are good! thanks so much!!

Comment: It's also possible that the lists were initialised with `arr0 = arr1 = arr2 = [None]` which results in the same behaviour because each array refers to the same list object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` like this:

```
for index, value in enumerate([arr0, arr1, arr2... arrN]):
    value[0] = index
```

But of course, this would fail with an `IndexError` if any of your arrays is an empty array. To fix that, you need to do this:

```
for index, value in enumerate([arr0, arr1, arr2... arrN]):
    if not value:
        value = [index]
    else:
        value[0] = index
```

You may read about `enumerate` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).